# Orthogonality of the annihilation operator in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, fourier-transform

In one of my QFT exercices it seems my teacher assumes

$$\int dp \int dp' a^†(p)a^†(p')\exp(ipx)\exp(ip'x')=0.$$

Could someone tell me why that is?

Comment: What are you integrating over? Is it a double integral?

Comment: @ytlu so two particles can't exist at different points?

Comment: I don't think this is equal to $0$. Can you explain the context in which this comes up in your teacher's note? It is certainly true that $[a^{\dagger}(p), a^{\dagger}(p)]=0$ which might have been used?

Comment: @ytlu this is not a function of $x$. $x_1$ and $x_2$ are labels of different modes in the field theory. How do you think you create a state with two particles at different locations in QFT?

Comment: @QuantumEyedea is correct. This is not zero. When you say "it seems my teacher assumes" please provide the context. You are probably misinterpreting something.

Comment: If they are *fermion* creation opertors (which you don't say), then the integral vanishes by Fermi statistics as it is symmetric in $p$ $p'$..

Comment: @mikestone It's not symmetric if $x\neq x'$. But maybe that's a typo in the question.

Comment: @JoshuaTS. You are right.